# Instantly getting location from location service After enable

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location, android-location

My location is disabled on my device. I have an application that requires the latitude and longitude. 
After launching the app , I have created an AlterDialog which asks if the location should be checked or not.
If I click ON then it will navigate to the device location screen and manually press ON .
Unfortunately if I press back then it gives me null latitude longitude.

I need to get the latitude longitude instantly after a click on the location ON on Back press of the location screen of the device .

Thanks in advance.

**Alert Dialog:**

```
 private void showAlert() {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,  final int id) {
                           startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            finish();
                       }
                   });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
```

Comment: No you can't. Implement the Location Listener in your code and Check locaion service is opened and which one opened? Network or GPS. If it network, yeah you get it "suddenly", but if GPS you have to wait till it connected. Use handler thread to wait GPS location, or get it from listeners other event.

Comment: @Metehan Toksoy thanks